# 'ptsize' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a graphical slot machine and have hit a few stumbling points which have ground development to a halt. The following is that I receive this error when trying to draw text to the screen.

```
TypeError: 'ptsize' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

This is weird because it works in Python 3.3 but I develop in 3.4.1 at home so is there a way to fix this and make it backwards compatible with 3.3?

The first line with the problem:

```
font.render_to(Display.screen, (680,130), "1", (random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),random.randint(0,255),255), None, rotation = 0, ptsize = 48)
```

Gist with the whole project - https://gist.github.com/tobias76/3b29c1ff59a64794e4ba

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keyword argument is now called `size`, *not* `ptsize`; from the [`Font.render_to()` documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to):

```
render_to(surf, dest, text, fgcolor=None, bgcolor=None,
          style=STYLE_DEFAULT, rotation=0, size=0) -> Rect
```

At some point in 2013 the project renamed the `ptsize` argument to `size`, see [this revision](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/commits/b0f518dee1386e84db2435ef63b77e36d2a28603); you have an older version installed on one computer, a newer version on the other.

The Pygame release history is unclear, but I strongly suspect that it even depends on where you download the 1.9.2a0 release from wether or not that change is part of the build!

Comment: I have now included some extremely primitive backwards compatibility which may or may not help the program work in both enviornments.